# What is the right way to GET a new webpage

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api, web-frontend

Let's say I have 2 webpages: index.html (the login page) and home.html

Once a user successfully logs in on index.html and is authenticated with a sessionID, I want to navigate them to /home

Issue is: how exactly do I GET the home.html page? If I use fetch API/XHR, I can pass the sessionID and get the home.html webpage in response, BUT the url does not change to /home. So if the user refreshes the page, it takes them back to index.html. If I simply use window.href="/home", then my GET request is sent by the browser and it does not contain my sessionID, so I cannot authenticate the request at the server end...

**Basically my questions are:**

1. What is the best way to GET a new page? Ideally with the url reflecting the change in webpage and allowing for authentication
2. What is the best way to replace an existing page with the new page received as a response? I currently use document.write(response_html) which I think is not a good solution

Comment: What does "*logs in on index.html and is authenticated with a sessionID*" mean? If you are storing a session cookie, it will be sent with the GET request to load *home.html* just fine by the browser.

Comment: index.html i.e. the default landing page is my login page. they click Login button and it sends a post request which authenticates their credentials and returns a sessionID if successful. This sessionID I have stored as a session variable not cookie. Should I store it as a cookie instead?

Comment: If you want the browser to send it with every request, in particular with GET requests for other pages, then yes you should store it as a cookie. Otherwise you can only serve static html pages, and will need to all API calls that need authentication from your own clientside code.

Comment: thank you very much. so are you suggesting that: i use cookies instead of session variables, and then i can just navigate to whatever url i want as in window.href = "/newpage"? If you want, you can write your advice as an answer and I will mark it as such if nobody has any better solutions

Comment: What do you mean by "session variable"?

Comment: sessionStorage variable

Comment: Ah, that term is often used to refer to server-side state stored regarding to the session, so I was confused. Yes, use cookies, and normal address navigation will work.